# Question related to vertex cover

Tags: algorithms

The definition of vertex cover is as is:
Set of vertices such that each each has atleast one endpoint in that set. 
[image]

In the above example, why can't we consider all vertices as vertex cover since all vertices are endpoints to all the edges.

Comment: You absolutely can.

Answer (score 1):

Your misunderstanding might be a false assumption that there is a *unique* vertex cover. This is hardly the case – there could be many different ones.

The set of all vertices always forms a vertex cover. However, there are always smaller vertex covers (even in the complete graph!), and we are usually interested in finding a vertex cover which is as small in size as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As Yuval said, there is a trivial vertex cover for any graph, namely all the vertices.

The NP-complete problem is actually, "Is there a vertex cover of size $\le n$?"

The idea is to find the smallest set of vertices that form a vertex cover.

Comment: Yes, but be careful with notation. $n$ almost always denotes the number of  vertices in a graph, and the problem of "Is there a vertex cover of size at most the number of vertices?" is trivially in **P**.